# How to implement roles in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing a Spring MVC web application. I want to implement Spring Security for specific roles. I have three roles: user, admin and customer.

Here is my code sample:

**`context-security.xml`**

```xml
<global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
</global-method-security>

<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/img/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/login*" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.xhtml">
    <anonymous enabled='false' />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/user**"
        access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/cutomer**"
        access="ROLE_CUSTOMER" />

    <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        login-page="/login.xhtml"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="customSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/login" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login"
        invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
    class="com.invetechs.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />

<authentication-manager
    alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider
        ref="customAuthenticationProvider">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**`HappyfacesUserDetails`**

```java
public static final class HappyfacesUserDetails implements UserDetails {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** User. */
    private User user;

    /** Constructor. */
    private HappyfacesUserDetails(User user) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUserName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        roles.add(new GrantedAuthority() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public String getAuthority() {

                if (user.getId() == -1L)
                    return "ROLE_ADMIN";
                else if (user.getId() == 1L )
                    return "ROLE_CUSTOMER";
                else
                    return "ROLE_USER";
            }

        });

        return roles;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

 }
```

**project directories**

[image: project directories image]

**More details**

The project has three main roles: admin, user and customer. Every role has the privileges to access the pages in the directory contains the role name from the web app directory. For example: user role can access the pages inside the directory user and the same for the other roles.

At the current situation the admin can access every directory and the other roles cannot access any thing in the application.

I think my problem is in the `context-security` file but I can not figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Your `/**` rule is the first and as such matches everything. The order in which the rules are defined is also the order in which they are consulted!. So move your `/**` as the last rule to match instead of the first.

Answer (score 0):

The order of `interpect-url` is important, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-intercept-url):

> **43.1.24 <intercept-url>**
>
> This element is used to define the set of URL patterns that the application is interested in and to configure how they should be handled. It is used to construct the `FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource` used by the `FilterSecurityInterceptor`. It is also responsible for configuring a `ChannelProcessingFilter` if particular URLs need to be accessed by HTTPS, for example. When matching the specified patterns against an incoming request, the matching is done in the order in which the elements are declared. So the most specific patterns should come first and the most general should come last.

Your modified part of configuration:

```xml
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.xhtml">
    <anonymous enabled='false' />

    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/user**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/cutomer**" access="ROLE_CUSTOMER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

    <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login.xhtml" authentication-success-handler-ref="customSuccessHandler" authentication-failure-url="/login" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>
```